# ¿Por qué cuando itero este array de números en C++ me sale al final del recorrido un número negativo?

Tags: c++

Intento iterar un array de números del 1 al 10 en C++, lo logro pero al final se me ejecuta un número negativo ¿A qué se debe esto? porque no me sale ningún error de compilación. Acá dejo el código:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int numeros[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

    for(int i=0; i<=10; i++) {
        cout<<numeros[i]<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cuando se utiliza array en cualquier lenguaje, o por lo menos en muchos de estos (C, C++, C#, Java, Javascript, php, python, VB, entre otros) estos deben de ser recorridos desde la posición **0** hasta la posición del **tamaño-1**.

En tu caso el **tamaño es de 10** razon por la cual tu debes de recorrerlo solo hasta la posición **9** que es igual al **tamaño-1 (10-1=9)**.

Entonces tu error esta en la condición de tu `for` de : `i<=10`, lo cual hace que **i** cause un desbordamiento de pila(stack overflow) cuando se aplique `cout<<numeros[10]<<endl;` posición que no esta reservada dentro de tu variable **numeros** , razón por la cual al final te imprime un **negativo** o mejor dicho una **direccion de memoria** ya que es eso lo que imprime.

Solucion:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

    int main() {

    int numeros[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        cout<<numeros[i]<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Si notas solo cambie el **i<=10** por **i<10**.

Comment: Es cierto, no se por qué se me pasó. Gracias.